# How to categorize features based on hstore values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, sql, attribute-table, osm2pgsql

I have a table with the columns of id,tags(hstore data type) and geometry.
I want to categorize the table based on selecting the specific key form tags:
for example:

```
select * FROM table_name WHERE tags @> 'public_transport=>stop_position'
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**In QGIS 3.4**, you can use the `hstore_to_map` expression to get a map (dictionary) of the hstore field. Then you can use one of the map expressions to manipulate it:

[image: access hstore value]

**In QGIS 3.6**, you can use the "explode hstore field" which will create one field for each keys in the hstore field:

[image: explode hstore field]

Answer (score 2):

**Solution with QGIS 2.18**

You need the plugin 'Expressions plus'.  Then you can perform queries on a hstore-column.

If you choose 'Categorized' and use an expression-based column you can categorize values within a certain key: `hstore_get_value(other_tags, 'surface')`

[image]

**For QGIS 3** I haven't found a way to perform that

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HSTORE operators in standard QGIS expression like that.

However if your back-end database is Postgres, and you have installed the HSTORE extension (to ensure your operators like => are defined) then you may be able to use them in Database Manager SQL queries.

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, then a Postgres query that uses a [CASE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) to allocate these values to a new column in your table would work. (Or you could create a new MATERIALIZED VIEW using the same technique)