# How to activate "explode hstore field" in QGIS 3.6

Tags: postgis, qgis-3

In [How to categorize features based on hstore values in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209421/how-to-categorize-features-based-on-hstore-values-in-qgis#288550) somebody said: "In QGIS 3.6, you can use the "explode hstore field" which will create one field for each keys in the hstore field"

but i can't find this functionality. Running QGIS 3.6.2

Regards
walter

Answer (score 1):

Had to do a reboot of my system (running 24/7/365) after about 4 weeks. After that the toolbox was growing really big (~100 functions) and "explode hstore" was availiable.

Strange.

Regards
walter