# Getting the value of OSM tag contained in the 'other_tag' field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, openstreetmap

I got my data from OSM and a lot of metadata is stored in field `"other_tags"`, which is in itself an HSTORE key/value field. For instance, my `"other_tags"` contains a key `voltage` with value `"150000"` as I'm processing power lines for my application.

How do I access the information in that field programmatically? This is what I've got so far:

```py
features = self.source.getFeatures()
for current, feature in enumerate(features):
    fields = feature.fields()
    idx = fields.indexOf("other_tags")
    otherTags = fields.field(idx)
    # and now?
```

Unfortunately the documentation on [`QgsField`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Field/QgsField.html) is very sparse, contains no examples and has cryptic parameter names like `v` that don't say anything to me.

EDIT: An example of the `"other_tags"` field:

`"circuits"=>"1","frequency"=>"50","layer"=>"-1","location"=>"underground","operator"=>"TenneT","power"=>"cable","voltage"=>"150000"`

Comment: You can always edit the _attributes_ key of the _osmconfig.ini_ file to include the tags that you want as separate fields. https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your script, `fields.field(idx)` returns `QgsField` object, not field value. You can get the value using one of the followings:

```
feature.attribute("other_tags")
# OR
feature.attribute(idx) # in your script
# OR 
feature["other_tags"]
```

In OSM data, `other_tags` field is string. You need to parse it to get the desired value. OSM data may include many tags. Therefore, in QGIS, new fields are generated for the common tags. Other tags, which are not common, are added to `other_tags` field.

```
for feature in features:

    # get field value
    tags = feature["other_tags"]
    # OR
    # tags = feature.attribute("other_tags")
    
    # convert to list
    tags = tags.split(",")
    
    # get the item containing "voltage" string
    voltage_str = [t for t in tags if "voltage" in t]
    
    if voltage_str: # if voltage tag exists
    
        # split by '=>', remove " from the second item
        voltage = voltage_str[0].split("=>")[1].replace('"', '')
```

Comment: Excellent. Somehow I didn't expect feature["other_tags"] to return something different than 
```fields = feature.fields()
idx = fields.indexOf("other_tags")
tags = fields.field(idx)``` but it did. Thanks!

Comment: `fields.field(idx)` returns QgsField object.

Answer (score 3):

The `other_tags` is a HStore strings. There is a function in the API to parse such strings. You shouldn't parse it yourself.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import NULL
from qgis.core import QgsHstoreUtils

# define your "features" variable

for feature in features:
    tags = feature["other_tags"]
    
    if tags == NULL:
        # The "other_tags" field can be empty
        continue
    
    tags = QgsHstoreUtils.parse(tags)
    print(tags.get('voltage'))
    # You will get either the value or None if the key does not exist for that feature.
```

HStore : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/hstore.html

Source : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/303803/24505